# Is there a ReSharper annotation for regex highlighting?

Tags: c#, regex, resharper, visual-studio-2015

I like to add annotations like `StringFormatMethod` to my formatting methods, so ReSharper highlights format parameters etc.

ReSharper also has syntax highlighting for regular expressions, and I would like the same treatment of regex patterns in my own extension method `ReplaceRegex`:

[image: Regular expresssions syntax highlighting]

Notice how the `\s*` is highlighted only in `Regex.Replace`.

I looked in the `Jetbrains.Annotations` namespace, but could not find any relevant attributes. Is there currently no way to do this?

Comment: I am afraid it is a dupe of [How do I make my own method similar to String.Format using Composite Formatting in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12092296/3832970). Is that the answer to your question?

Comment: @stribizhev looks like it, except that the relevant attribute here would seem to be [`RegexPatternAttribute`](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Reference__Code_Annotation_Attributes.html)

Comment: @AakashM, thank you for the answer, if you post it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @stribizhev as AakashM commented, this is about a different attribute. Specifically my problem was that I was referring to an old Jetbrains.Annotations. Please un-mark this as a duplicate so I can add an answer, in case anyone else has the same problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out the problem was I had an old version of `Jetbrains.Annotations`.

The attribute I was looking for was `RegexPatternAttribute`, found in [this NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JetBrains.Annotations/).

Here is my extension method with the attribute:

```
    public static string ReplaceRegex(this string str, [RegexPattern] string pattern, string replacement, RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.None) {
        return Regex.Replace(str, pattern, replacement, options);
    }
```

Now I get the fancy coloring for my extension method:
[image: Regex syntax highlighting]

Thanks to @AakashM for the comment with the answer!

Comment: Speaking of older annotations - here's a useful link to how to get annotations added to your project: http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2015/08/12/how-to-use-jetbrains-annotations-to-improve-resharper-inspections/

Comment: @citizenmatt wasn't there some feature added to respond to // lang=regex or something? i am currently looking for that feature but i can't remember the exact syntax and it's not documented in https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.1/Regular_Expressions_Assistance.html

Comment: Yep, `//language=regexp`. See more details in the recent blog post: https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2016/12/26/language-injections-in-resharper-ultimate-2016-3/